# Bifurcation Diagram- The Logistic Map

Tags: bifurcation

I recently got to know about the logistic map, given by $f(x) = rx(1-x)$, and it’s bifurcation diagram when mapped as $r$ along the x-axis.

At $r=3.56995 (approx.)$ we enter the chaotic part with some islands of stability.

All this continues till $r=4$.

But what about $r>4$. Why doesn’t the diagram include it?

What type of behaviour is observed after $r>4$? Does the map become more chaotic or something else happens?

Please help in explaining it to me.

Edit: I checked about it on Google but couldn’t find anything!

Comment: We want to map the range $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$. This does not work for $r>4$.

Comment: Can I ask why it happens ?

Comment: If we take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ , we get outside the range $[0,1]$ in the case $r>4$

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @Moo, thank you for that. I guess I just ignored the last point due to the fact that there were larger points before. Sorry, for inconvenience.